# Stub/spy on singleton with Sinon

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, sinon, stub, spy

I have a need to write some unit tests where I check on calls to singleton functions.  Basically, if I have this:

```
const somePackage = require('some-package');
```

And am calling it with:

```
somePackage();
```

I want to be able to spy/stub on this singleton call to prove that it was called. I know how to do this with methods using `sinon.stub(somePackage, 'someMethod')` but not for just a singleton.

Right now I actually have to write integration tests by executing the code when in reality I want to write unit tests and show that these external methods were called. I'm trusting that the developer of those packages did their own testing for the functionality.

Answer (score 0):

You can spy on any function with sinon:

```
const spy = sinon.spy(myFunc);
```

To stub a single function you can use `proxyquire` as described in this [issue](https://github.com/sinonjs/sinon/issues/562):

```
const proxyquire = require('proxyquire')
const sinon = require('sinon')
const sum = sinon.stub()

const ModuleWithDependency = proxyquire('module', {
  'sum': sum
})
```